# Simple Filter based on two select options by changing url

Tags: php, html, jquery

Hie, i am trying to filter based on url change on two select options. Not sure how to go about it but i tried something below and nothing seems to be working
Html code

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label>Select Year: </label>
  <select class="form-control input-sm" id="select_year">
    <?php                         
      date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
      $today = date('y-m-d');
      $year = date('Y');
      $currentyear = date('Y');
      if(isset($_GET['year'])){
        $year = $_GET['year'];
      }
      for($i=2019; $i<=$currentyear; $i++){
        $selected = ($i==$year)?'selected':'';
        echo "
          <option value='".$i."' ".$selected.">".$i."</option>
        ";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <label>Select Continent: </label>
  <select class="form-control input-sm" id="select_continent">
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Americas/Central/South/Latin/">Africa</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="filter-form">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Js Code

```
$(function(){
  $('#filter-form').click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'view-report.php?year='+$('select_year').val()'&continent='+$('#select_continent').val();
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem ? Can you read your browser console to see if you don't have any JS error ? `$('select_year').val()`, you forgot the `#` in your selector

Comment: You also forgot a `+` between `$('select_year').val()` and `'&continent='`. I think we can say the problem here is syntax.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it was the syntax, but now the problem is the year is like year=undefined

Comment: The issue is in the line where you're constructing the URL for redirection. You are missing the # symbol before the select_year in the jQuery selector. correct Code : window.location.href = 'view-report.php?year=' + $('#select_year').val() + '&continent=' + $('#select_continent').val();

Comment: Thanks @DruviShah didn't notice now its working thanks!!

Comment: A slightly _simpler_ way to do this: Give your select fields the appropriate `name` (`year`, and `continent`), and then just `location.href = 'view-report.php?' + $(this.form).serialize();`

Comment: Why not get rid of the Javascript and simply submit the form?

Comment: @brombeer will have to write lot of code that will return data to the same page in the end will use jquery, as will try and avoid page reload and all those thing. Using location.href is the quickest way

Comment: So `location.href` doesn't reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complex than it needs to be - you can just use a FORM submitting via GET and it will produce the URL you want.

```
<form method="get" action="view-report.php" class="form-inline">
  <label for="select_year">Select Year: </label>
  <select name="year" class="form-control input-sm" id="select_year">
    <?php                         
      date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');

      $year_option = 2019;
      $year_current = $year_selected = date('Y');
      if( isset( $_GET['year'] ) )
        $year_selected = $_GET['year'];
      while( $year_option <= $year_current ){
        echo sprintf( '<option%s>%s</option>' ,
          ( $year_option == $year_selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) ,
          $year_option
        );
        $year_option++; 
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <label for="select_continent">Select Continent: </label>
  <select name="continent" class="form-control input-sm" id="select_continent">
    <?php
      $continent_list = array(
        'Africa' => 'Africa' ,
        'America' => 'Americas/Central/South/Latin' ,
        'Australia' => 'Australia' ,
        'Europe' => 'Europe'
      );
      $continent_selected = false;
      if( isset( $_GET['continent'] ) )
        $continent_selected = $_GET['continent'];
      foreach( $continent_list as $label => $value ){
        echo sprintf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>' ,
          $value ,
          ( $value == $continent_selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) ,
          $label
        );
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It works as well, just tested it!